# Attach sqlite3 database in c++

Tags: c++, sqlite

Is there a way to attach a sqlite3 database to an existing connection without using the sqlite3_exec command?
Is there a way to do that using the sqlite3_prepare_v2 command?

Regards

Comment: You may find C++ wrapper to SQLite, such as kompex' one : http://sqlitewrapper.kompex-online.com/index.php?content=download (sources are also on github, see the page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this by using the sqlite3_step function:

```
 sqlite3_step(statement);
```